# the best approach to giving an error message when validating

Tags: php

I am a new programmer and am attempting to do some validation for a basic registration form. I have built a basic registration form that sends the user back to the same page when submitted. I have also created a user class and have created some basic validation functions. However, the functions have the error messages built into them. I obviously put the functions on the top of the registration form so when there is an error the errors are posted on the registration form. However, I have no control on how the error messages look and would like to know if there is a lot better way to somehow echo the error messages from outside the class so I can use some type of css or something else for better control of how they look. I hope that makes sense. Also when there is an error the user is sent back to an empty registration form. I was trying to figure out how to keep the valid information in the text boxes and just make them redo the invalid information. Here is a basic example of a validation I have done. I know its basic but I am very new to programming

```
function validate_password($password)
{   
    $valid = TRUE;
    if ($password == '')
    {
        echo "<p> Please enter a value for the password </p>";
            $valid = FALSE;
    }
    elseif($_POST['pwd'] !== $_POST['pwd2'])
        {
            echo "The passwords do not match please try again";
            $valid = FALSE;
        }
return $valid;
}
```

Comment: I meant to say it sends the user back to the same page only when there is an error. If not it sends them to the home page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't echo them right away, instead store them for later use.  You mentioned this is inside a class, so you can use a class property to hold error messages.

class YourClass
{
    public $error;

```
function validate_password($password)
{   
    $valid = TRUE;
    if ($password == '')
    {
        // Set the error message
        $this->error = "Please enter a value for the password";
            $valid = FALSE;
    }
    // etc...
}
```

}

Later, when you need to, you can output it in the HTML:

```
if (!empty($yourclass->error)) {
  echo "<p class='errmsg'>{$yourclass->error}</p>\n";
}
```

You then just need a CSS class `errmsg` and you can style it how you like:

```
.errmsg {
   color: #FF0000;
   font-size: 36px;
}
```

Now if you have that working, you can expand it further to make the `$error` class property into an array and push multiple messages onto it:

```
// In the class, initialize it as an array
$this->error = array();


// Use the [] notation to append messages to the array.
$this->error[] = "Another error message..."
$this->error[] = "And yet another error message..."
```

In your presentation code, use a loop to output the messages:

```
// Output a big stack of error messages...
foreach ($yourclass->error as $err) {
      echo "<p class='errmsg'>$err</p>\n";
}
```

Comment: thank you I have been struggling to figure this out for hours

Comment: @Mike the Z Glad to help. And check out the bit I just added about keeping an array of error messages.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do with classes and their errors is have a variable specifically for the errors.
So something like:

```
class User
{
    private $_ValidationErrors = array();

    function validate_password($password)
    {   
        $this->_ValidationErrors = array();
        $valid = TRUE;
        if ($password == '')
        {
            $this->_ValidationErrors[] = "Please enter a value for the password";
                $valid = FALSE;
        }
        elseif($_POST['pwd'] !== $_POST['pwd2'])
        {
            $this->_ValidationErrors[] = "The passwords do not match please try again";
            $valid = FALSE;
        }
        return $valid;
    }

    function ValidationErrors ()
    {
        if (count($this->_ValidationErrors) == 0)
            return FALSE;
        return $this->_ValidationErrors;
    }
}
```

Then to use:

```
$user = new User();
if (!$user->validate_password('somepass'))
    echo implode('<BR>',$user->ValidationErrors ());
```

EDIT: To display errors by the user something like:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $user = new User();
    $passwordErrors = (!$user->validate_password($_POST["pass1"]))?$user->ValidationErrors():array();
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["php_self"]; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="pass1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["pass1"]); ?>" /><BR/>
    <?php
        echo ((isset($passwordErrors) && count($passwordErrors) == 0)?"":implode("<BR/>", $passwordErrors));
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Comment: now is there a way to make the errors appear specifically in the box that was not valid?